# MediaElement buffering twice

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm using a MediaElement to play a video and using the BufferingProgressChanged event to update a progress bar when buffering occurs. However, when the BufferingProgress property of the MediaElement reaches 1 it resets back to 0 and then buffesr to 1 again. As a result the progress shows twice, which looks strange to the user.

Any idea why this happens and how to prevent it?

I've seen others ask this question, but no answers so far. I guess it's a non trivial problem, hope one of you experts can help!

P.S if you don't know the answer, can you vote for this question so it gets brought to the attention of more people? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the encoding of the video.
Encoding using Expression Encoder resolved the problem.